# "/usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found" when trying to install apt-transport-https

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

When I try to run any apt-get command, I get the error::

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?
```

My first instinct was to try to `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`, so I did that, only to get the same error message after appearing to begin the download. So I checked many of the dozens of similar questions on this site and found that most recommended `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`. So, to make sure I just didn't make some dumb mistake, I tried this again, and it still didn't work.

Others recommended checking for typos in sources.list, and I found nothing but http:// on every link in there, so that can't be the problem as far as I know.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Docker container. I can also ping, so I don't think it's an Internet issue. Also, `sources.list.d` is empty.

EDIT

Running `sudo apt-get update --print-uris` gives:

```
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_source_Sources 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_restricted_source_Sources 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_source_Sources 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_InRelease 0
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_source_Sources 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/source/Sources.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_source_Sources 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/source/Sources.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_universe_source_Sources 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_InRelease 0
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/source/Sources.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_source_Sources 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/source/Sources.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_source_Sources 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/source/Sources.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_source_Sources 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_InRelease 0
```

Comment: Add the output of `sudo apt-get update --print-uris`.

Comment: @muru I've done as you asked

Comment: Huh, not a single HTTPS URL. It might be a bug and worth reporting. In the meantime, try `apt-get download apt-transport-https` and manually install it using `dpkg -i`.

Comment: I don't think it's an Ubuntu bug, I think it's how the docker Ubuntu image has been configured - is there a way I can manually download apt-transport-https from the terminal?